# What does the '...rest' stand for in this object destructuring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, spread-syntax

I'm reading about unknown-prop warnings in react, particularly because I'm using the react-bootstrap package and have stumbled upon them there.

i've read that: 'To fix this, composite components should "consume" any prop that is intended for the composite component and not intended for the child component', on here:

https://gist.github.com/jimfb/d99e0678e9da715ccf6454961ef04d1b

and an example is given for how the spread operator can be used to pull variables off props, and put the remaining props into a variable.

the example code:

```
function MyDiv(props) {
  const { layout, ...rest } = props
  if (layout === 'horizontal') {
    return <div {...rest} style={getHorizontalStyle()} />
  } else {
    return <div {...rest} style={getVerticalStyle()} />
  }
}
```

Here is what the PROBLEM is: In the example given, I don't understand what the '...rest' in this code here stands for. I get that the '...' = spread syntax, but where did the word 'rest' come from and what does it stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is object [rest syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), it creates an object from all properties that weren't explicitly destructured.

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const { a, ...everythingElse } = obj;

console.log(a);

console.log(everythingElse);
```

It's equivalent to array rest syntax:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const [a, ...rest] = arr;

console.log(a);
console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse rest syntax (`...`) and spread syntax (that is also `...`):

`...` acts as a rest syntax in the code below:

```
const { layout, ...rest } = props
```

but in the code below, `...` acts as a spread syntax:

```
return <div {...rest} style={getHorizontalStyle()} />
```