# what does this assignment means in this render method of a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `render` method of `CopyButton` component,  we have the line:

`const { classes, theme, hidden, ...other } = this.props;`

What does it mean? `=` is an assigngment operator, and an object(denoted by the `{}`) is its
left value? How can an object be the left value of an assignment?

Besides, what does `...other` mean, I know that `...` is a expand operator, but what does `other` stand for?

---

Below is the whole piece of codes:

```
export class CopyButton extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    theme: PropTypes.object,

    hidden: PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    //赋值操作的左值是一个对象？
    const { classes, theme, hidden, ...other } = this.props;

    const copyIconStyle =
      theme.direction === 'ltr' ? null : { transform: 'scaleX(-1)' };

    return (
      <Scannable disabled={hidden}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Copy" className={classes.button} {...other}>
          <FileCopy className={classes.icon} style={copyIconStyle} />
        </IconButton>
      </Scannable>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's called destructuring, and it can be done with arrays and objects. In this case it's with the props object, here's some documentation about object destructuring: https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring

Comment: It's object destructuring assignment ... more info here [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the '...rest' stand for, in this spread operator example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689680/what-does-the-rest-stand-for-in-this-spread-operator-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is object [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) combined with the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
const { classes, theme, hidden, ...other } = this.props;
```

The `props` object may have properties that are then destructured and assigned to local variables. In this case, `classes`, `theme`, `hidden`, and the rest of the properties (*via the spread syntax*) are assigned to an object named `other`.

```js
const props = {
  classes: 'this is a value',
  theme: 'foo',
  hidden: false,
  otherProp1: 'other 1',
  otherProp2: {
    nestedProp: 'nested value',
  },
};

const { classes, theme, hidden, ...other } = props;

console.log(classes);
console.log(theme);
console.log(hidden);
console.log(other);
```

Comment: After the destruction, `this.props` still holds  these values(chasses,thems,hidden,...), right?

Comment: @ZhaoGang ***Destructure***, not destruction. And correct, destructuring leaves the original object/array intact. Also, in React state and props are treated as immutable.